# PHP - do/while go to the next in array if result is empty

Tags: php

I have following list:

```
$radiusList = [
    '2'   => '2km',
    '5'   => '5km',
    '10'  => '10km',
    '25'  => '25km',
    '50'  => '50km',
    '100' => '100km',
    '200' => '200km',
    '500' => '500km',
];
```

I am getting currently selected radius via **POST**:

```
$radius = $_POST['radius'] ? $_POST['radius'] : 2;
```

And I have to go to the next radius if the result is empty. This is my **do/while loop**:

```
$clinics     = [];
$radiusCount =  count($radiusList);
$i = 0;

do {

    $radius  = $radiusList[$radius];

    $clinics = $this->clinicQuery($conditionsQuery, $lat, $lng, $radius);
    $i++;

} while  (!empty($clinics) && $i <= $radiusCount);
```

How can I set current radius (from the radius list) and if the result from the **clinicQuery** is empty go to the next element in the array and take key value?

Comment: This would be a bit easier if you would not use an associative array to begin with (which seems rather superfluous, since all your values are just the key suffixed with `km` anyway) … Make that `$radiusList = [2, 5, 10, …]` instead, and then simply find the index of your POSTed value in that, and use it as starting value for `$i`, so that inside your loop you can use that _index_ to access the values.

Comment: This is quite good idea. I guess I got code blindness I tried to go with more complicated way. That a lot for the idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your loop with `foreach` + `break`:

```
$radius = $_POST['radius'] ? $_POST['radius'] : 2;

foreach ($radiusList as $index => $radius_str) {
    // check that current index value is greater or equals `$radius`
    // it will skip values that are less than `$radius`
    if ($index >= $radius) {
        // find clinics
        $clinics = $this->clinicQuery($conditionsQuery, $lat, $lng, $index);
        // if clinics found - break the loop
        if (!empty($clinics)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a foreach instead.

```
$clinics = [];
$radiusList = array_filter($radiusList, function($index) use ($radius) {
    return $index >= $radius;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
ksort($radiusList); // if you need to make sure the list is ordered
foreach ($radiusList as $distance => $distanceLabel) {
    $clinics = $this->clinicQuery($conditionsQuery, $lat, $lng, $radius);
    if (!empty($clinics)) {
        break;
    }
}
```